# vba Run-time Error 75 during file rename

Tags: vba, file, io

I routine searches for images and moves the files that are images.
The code works inconsistently.
Sometime, it gives error 75.
Sometimes it works just fine.
The problem is in the following line:

Name MoveFrom as MoveTo

Where MoveFrom is the source file name.
MoveTo is the target file name (in a different folder--subfolder \Exceptions\Images, relateve to the MoveFrom Folder).

Any ideas of how to move this file consistently without this blasted error...

To assist, I have marked the problem line with comments as follows in the code:

```
'--------------------------------------------------------------------
' ------------PROBLEM HERE
'--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

...THE CODE:

```
Public Sub MoveImages()
'            ShellCommand = ActiveWorkbook_UNC_Path + "\cpdf.exe -list-fonts " + Chr(34) + ActiveWorkbook_UNC_Path + "\" + t + Chr(34) + " > " + Chr(34) + ActiveWorkbook_UNC_Path + "\" + "fontlist.txt" + Chr(34)
'            ShellCommand = ActiveWorkbook_UNC_Path + "\cpdf.exe -missing-fonts " + Chr(34) + ActiveWorkbook_UNC_Path + "\" + t + Chr(34) + " > " + Chr(34) + ActiveWorkbook_UNC_Path + "\" + "fontlist.txt" + Chr(34)

    'On Error GoTo 0

    Dim FileList As Variant
    FileList = GetFileList(ActiveWorkbook_UNC_Path + "\*.pdf")
    RunMoveImagesCount = RunMoveImagesCount + 1

    Dim t As String
    Dim Ndx As Integer
    Dim ShellCommand
    Dim ReturnCode As Long
    Dim WshShell As Variant
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim MoveFrom As String
    Dim MoveTo As String



    If IsArray(FileList) Then
        For Ndx = LBound(FileList) To UBound(FileList)

            t = FileList(Ndx)

            ShellCommand = "cpdf.exe -list-fonts " + Chr(34) + t + Chr(34) + " > fontlist.txt"


            ShellCommand = "cmd.exe /c " + ShellCommand


            ReturnCode = WshShell.Run(ShellCommand, 0, True)


            If FileLen(ActiveWorkbook_UNC_Path + "\" + "fontlist.txt") > 0 Then
                If RunMoveImagesCount > 1 Then
                    'not an image
                    ActiveCell.Value = "Warning!  Detected PDF, not converted to CSV  "
                    ActiveCell.Font.ColorIndex = 5
                    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
                End If
            Else
                'possibly not an image
                ShellCommand = "cpdf.exe -missing-fonts " + Chr(34) + t + Chr(34) + " > fontlist.txt"



                ShellCommand = "cmd.exe /c " + ShellCommand


                ReturnCode = WshShell.Run(ShellCommand, 0, True)

                If FileLen(ActiveWorkbook_UNC_Path + "\" + "fontlist.txt") > 0 Then
                    If RunMoveImagesCount > 1 Then
                        'not an image
                        ActiveCell.Value = "Warning!  Detected PDF(s), not converted to CSV  "
                        ActiveCell.Font.ColorIndex = 5
                        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
                    End If

                Else
                    'an image.... move it....

                    MoveFrom = ActiveWorkbook_UNC_Path + "\" + t
                    MoveTo = ActiveWorkbook_UNC_Path + "\Exceptions\Images\" + t

                    MoveFrom = ReplaceUNC(MoveFrom)
                    MoveTo = ReplaceUNC(MoveTo)

                    If FileThere(MoveTo) Then
                        'Kill MoveFrom
                        'shouldn't happen, but if it does, lets leave it there and investigate....
                    Else


'--------------------------------------------------------------------
' ------------PROBLEM HERE
'--------------------------------------------------------------------

                        Name MoveFrom As MoveTo
                        ImageCount = ImageCount + 1




                    End If

                    MoveFrom = ReplaceLastOccurance(MoveFrom, ".pdf", ".csv")
                    If FileThere(MoveFrom) Then
                        MoveTo = ReplaceLastOccurance(MoveTo, ".pdf", ".csv")

                        If FileThere(MoveTo) Then
                            'Kill MoveFrom
                            'shouldn't happen, but if it does, lets leave it there and investigate....
                        Else
                            Name MoveFrom As MoveTo
                        End If
                    End If

                End If
            End If

        Next
    Else
        'no files; you're done.

    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: My guess is that your source and/or destination path are incorrect. For example, if the statement is `Name "C:\Temp\aaa.jpg" As "C:\Temp\SubFolder\aaa.jpg"` and the `SubFolder` does not exist, you'll get this error. My suggestion is to check for the existence of the destination folder/path before the rename. That way you can create the path appropriately before the move.

Comment: No.  I actually changed Name MoveFrom as MoveTo   ::  fso.CopyFile MoveFrom, MoveTo, True    :: followed by Kill MoveFrom.      I crash on Kill.    It complains I don't have previledge when in fact I know I do.  It works inconsistently.  When directory has large volume of files, it seems to not work.

Comment: Are you on a server? It could be the security level, sometimes you can create and change files, but you cannot delete, it depends on what you are allowed to do in that folder. If you can do it manually that means the code can do it too

Comment: I'm getting the same error.

VBA randomly stops on Name f1 as f2 with a path/file access error. I click continue without altering anything and the code runs without issue. It's extremely frustrating since the error randomly triggers.